# How to set no of request in SOAP UI?

Tags: soapui, load-testing

I am new to Soap UI and I want to send same request multiple times(100 times).it is like performance test.Is there any option to test like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes, it is possible to do so by using Load Test.

I believe that you have created a [test case](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/structuring-and-running-tests.html).

Just right click on the test case, choose `New Load Test`.

There are different strategies for load testing. Of course, it allows you to set the number of times a test needs to be executed.

You can find more details [here](https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/creating-and-running-loadtests.html)